# How to create stub for ajax function using Jasmine BDD

Tags: ajax, unit-testing, bdd, jasmine

I'm struggling to find any examples on how to fake an ajax call using Jasmine BDD?

I have a custom ajax function that works like so...

```
ajax({
    url: 'JSON.php',
    dataType: 'json',           
    onSuccess: function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
    }
});
```

...and I've no idea how to create a stub to fake calling the actual ajax function.

I want to avoid calling the ajax function as it could slow down my test suite if a real ajax call to the server takes some time to respond and I've loads of specs in my test suite.

I've heard that you can use `spyOn(namespace, 'ajax')` but that is annoying straight away as it requires me to wrap my `ajax` function in an object just to use the `spyOn` function (but regardless I wasn't able to follow along as I couldn't find any specific examples to fake an ajax call).

I've also heard that you can use `createSpy()` but again the documentation isn't very helpful (neither is the corresponding wiki on GitHub).

Any help explaining how to use spies to create a fake ajax call would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use SinonJS mocking framework, which has a build in [fake server](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#server). You can easily use it with jasmine:

```
beforeEach(function() {
        server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
        server.respondWith([200, { "Content-Type": "text/html", "Content-Length": 2 }, "OK"])
});
```

Btw. if your ajax function is in the global namespace why not call `spyOn(window, 'ajax')`

Comment: Thanks for this, I had started working on this myself already yesterday. See Gist: https://gist.github.com/1625810

Answer (score 0):

Regarding a single function, you may use 'createSpy':

```
/*var */ajax = createSpy('foo');
```

`var` is absent because you want to redefine it, but it is then required that the block where you define this spy is bound to the same scope where real `ajax` was defined. Or, if you confused with that, use `spyOn(window, foo)`, because you are anyway testing it in the browser.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9511646/167262) for details.

Regarding the ajax call, see [*Asynchronous Support* section](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/#section-Asynchronous_Support) in [new docs](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine), or better use [Clock](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/#section-Mocking_the_JavaScript_Clock):

```
window.ajax = function() {};

var response;

var ajaxSpy = spyOn(window, 'ajax').andCallFake(function(url, callback) {
   setTimeout(function() { callback({ 'foo': 'bar' }); }, 1000);
});

jasmine.Clock.useMock();

function callback(resp) { response = resp;  }

ajax('fake.url', callback);

jasmine.Clock.tick(1500);

expect(ajaxSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(response).toBeDefined();
expect(response.foo).toBeDefined();
```

Comment: An important thing to notice is that `Clock` mock in fact substitues `setTimeout` / `setInterval` calls so they will be called immediately, but in the specified order — this mock is done only to save you from waiting for timeouts

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with not using spies, but instead the add-on [jasmine-ajax](https://jasmine.github.io/edge/ajax.html). To mock for a single spec use `withMock`:

```
  it("allows use in a single spec", function() {
    var onSuccess = jasmine.createSpy('success');
    jasmine.Ajax.withMock(function() {
      ajax({
            url: 'JSON.php',
            dataType: 'json',           
            onSuccess: onSuccess
      });
      expect(onSuccess).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

      jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().respondWith({
        "status": 200,
        "responseText": '{"some": "json"}'
      });

      expect(onSuccess).toHaveBeenCalledWith('{"some": "json"}');
    });
  });
```

The response is only sent when you use `respondWith`. The link above has some directions how to install