# How to test XMLHttpRequest with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, ajax, jasmine

How can I test the onreadystatechange on XMLHttpRequest or pure Javascript AJAX without jQuery? I'm doing this because I'm developing Firefox extension. I guess I have to use spies, but couldn't figure out how because my ajax won't return anything.

```
    submit : function() {
        var url = window.arguments[0];
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST", 'http://'+this.host+'/doSomething', true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.send("param="+param+"&emotions="+this.getParams());
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(this.readyState == 4) {
                // alert(this.responseText);
            }
        };

    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create Stub for ajax function using Jasmine BDD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884060/how-to-create-stub-for-ajax-function-using-jasmine-bdd)

Comment: Well, that one is using jQuery, but I'm trying to use pure XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Sure but the answer (using SininJS mocking framework) is working for your case as well.

Comment: Sorry didn't think SininJS can do that. Thanks! Will try that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mention in the comments with [SinonJS](http://sinonjs.org/) you can easily [mock the XHR object / create a fake server](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#server).

Answer (score 39):

And what about this one?

```
beforeEach(function() {
  // spyOn(XMLHttpRequest.prototype, 'open').andCallThrough(); // Jasmine 1.x
  spyOn(XMLHttpRequest.prototype, 'open').and.callThrough(); // Jasmine 2.x
  spyOn(XMLHttpRequest.prototype, 'send');
});

...

it("should call proper YQL! API", function() {
  podcast.load_feed('http://www.faif.us/feeds/cast-ogg/');

  expect(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Pure Jasmine without need to use any external library.

Comment: This worked for me. But how to emulate xhr response handlers like onError, onLoad etc.?

Comment: Great answer, this helped me.

Answer (score 11):

Jasmine has [its own Ajax mock library called ajax.js](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/ajax.html).

Comment: Thanks @taro! I use `jasmine-ajax` and now, my test case looks really simple!

Demo: https://github.com/piecioshka/test-angular-services-testing/blob/master/src/app/photos.service.spec.ts#L84

Answer (score 5):

You can test it in such manner

```
it("should make XHR request", function() {

   // arrange

    var xhr = {
        open: jasmine.createSpy('open')
    };

    XMLHttpRequest = jasmine.createSpy('XMLHttpRequest');
    XMLHttpRequest.and.callFake(function () {
        return xhr;
    });

    // act

    submit();

    // assert

    expect(xhr.open).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
});
```

Comment: It could be a solution to the JavaScript project. In my Angular app TypeScript has complain for overriding XMLHttpRequest which is inferred to XMLHttpRequest interface.

Answer (score 1):

Provided by [jasmine-ajax](https://jasmine.github.io/edge/ajax.html). To mock for a single spec use `withMock`:

> ```
>   it("allows use in a single spec", function() {
>     var doneFn = jasmine.createSpy('success');
>     jasmine.Ajax.withMock(function() {
>       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
>       xhr.onreadystatechange = function(args) {
>         if (this.readyState == this.DONE) {
>           doneFn(this.responseText);
>         }
>       };
>
>       xhr.open("GET", "/some/cool/url");
>       xhr.send();
>
>       expect(doneFn).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
>
>       jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().respondWith({
>         "status": 200,
>         "responseText": 'in spec response'
>       });
>
>       expect(doneFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith('in spec response');
>     });
>   });
> ```

The response is only sent when you use `respondWith`. Just [download the file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jasmine/jasmine-ajax/master/lib/mock-ajax.js), and add as a `src` to your `SpecRunner.html`. Example usage at https://github.com/serv-inc/JSGuardian (see the test folder).

Comment: jasmine-ajax FTW — demo into my specs: https://github.com/piecioshka/test-angular-services-testing/blob/master/src/app/photos.service.spec.ts#L84

Answer (score -1):

As per the facsimile of your code below you will likely be able to inject console.log() with the status code and status text.

This will help you identify any http errors. Speculatively I'd say the status will return 404.

```
submit : function() {
    var url = window.arguments[0];
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", 'http://'+this.host+'/doSomething', true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send("param="+param+"&emotions="+this.getParams());
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log(this.status+ " - "+ this.statusText);
    };

}
```

An alternative to this would be to look at the request header / response within the firebug console. Which is a good point: If you're not using firebug or chrome dev tools you should change the console.log() call to something that appends the string to a document object **do not** use an alert() call.

[How do I verify jQuery AJAX events with Jasmine?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6199132/871580). A similar answer that implements Jasmine.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jasmine however I've added a link to my answer which points to an answer from a similar thread that appears to be the Jasmine test you're looking for.