# Jasmine Create Spy on Native JS Function on Global Window Object

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am writing a test to see if `Array.prototype.map` was called.  I thought this would work since Array.prototype.map is located on the global window object:

```
    it("does not use Array.prototype.map", function(){

        spyOn(window, "Array.prototype.map")
        fn([2,2,3]);
        expect(Array.prototype.map.calls.count()).toEqual(0);
    });
```

I receive the error `Array.prototype.map does not exist`.  When I create my own custom global functions, this method works fine.  [Based on this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510148/using-jasmine-to-spy-on-a-function-without-an-object) It appears any global functions can be spied on using the syntax I am using above.  If I create my own functions, this syntax works.  Any ideas on why `Array.prototype.map` is returning undefined?

Answer (score 3):

hopefully you already got your answer, but for people searching, it's because you should

```
spyOn(Array.prototype, 'map');
```