# Jasmine SpyOn Window Function in AngularJS Application

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, intercom.js

I've created a function as so upon route change:

```
window.intercom = function(action, msg) {
  return window.Intercom(action, msg);
};
```

Am trying to spy on this function but don't understand how. I followed the advice in [this SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510148/using-jasmine-to-spy-on-a-function-without-an-object)

If I use this:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $q, _$location_, $routeParams) {
  element = angular.element("<add-box></add-box>");
  $compile(element)($rootScope);
}));

it("should cancel adding a box!", function() {
  spyOn(window, 'intercom')
});
```

I get an error:

```
intercom() method does not exist
```

So I tried this:

```
it("should cancel adding a box!", function() {
  var intercom = jasmine.createSpy();
});
```

Which says:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'window.intercom('hide')')
```

How can I get this to work? I'm sure it's simple, I'm just new to Jasmine.

Comment: More context please. Send the actual test code.

Comment: @RobertMoskal Not much else in the tests at the moment as I was just trying to get them to run. Have made some changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about in the beforeEach or better in a before function you do something like this:

```
window.intercom = jasmine.createSpy();
```

That'll get you an intercom function on the window.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that previous but putting in the beforeeach block seems to work.