# Jasmine - How to Spy on a Function with no Implementation

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have my script (playground.efs) which I want to test.  However, it uses the eSignal API, so I have to spy any of those functions.

I'm having trouble setting up `spyOn`, I don't know what to object to spy on should be.  With testing `testEfsCode()`,  a spy for `getCurrentBarIndex()` needs to be created.  Since `getCurrentBarIndex()` isn't apart of any object how can I stub it?

The error I'm getting with my current code is:

> ```
> Error: <spyOn> : getCurrentBarIndex() method does not exist
> Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)
> ```

TestSpec.js

```
var util = require('../../../Interactive Data/Formulas/My Formulas/playground.efs');

describe("Utils", function() {
      it("should return true", function() {
            var spy = spyOn(util.testEfsCode, 'getCurrentBarIndex').and.callThrough();
            expect(util.testEfsCode()).toBe(true);
      });
});
```

playground.efs (Script To Test)

```
function testEfsCode(){
    getCurrentBarIndex();
    return true;
}

// Check For EFS
if ( typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.hasOwnProperty('exports') )
{
    module.exports = {
        testEfsCode: testEfsCode
    }
}
```

`getCurrentBarIndex()` is a function supplied by eSignal, so I don't have the code for it.  The function only runs when the script is loaded into eSignal.

Comment: Do you have any documentation for `getCurrentBarIndex`?  Where is it?  Is it a global function?  Have you tried spying with `spyOn(window, "getCurrentBarIndex")`?

Comment: `getCurrentBarIndex()` is a function supplied by eSignal.  You can only call it when you run the script inside of the eSignal application.  Also, I'm not using `window` in my code so I get ReferenceError: window is not defined

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure out the solution from this question [Using Jasmine to spy on a function without an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510148/using-jasmine-to-spy-on-a-function-without-an-object/9511646)

All I had to do was use `createSpy`

```
getCurrentBarIndex = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(8);
expect(util.testEfsCode()).toBe(8);
```

Comment: Woohoo! I was looking for this all over the place. Thanks man