# Using Jasmine to spy on a non-imported function without an object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I understand what's going on in: [Using Jasmine to spy on a function without an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510148/using-jasmine-to-spy-on-a-function-without-an-object) and why it doesn't work in TypeScript. I also see this TypeScript answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43532075/2548010.

Unfortunately this only solves the case for imported spied on functions. I am testing a function that takes in a function, and I am trying to see that the passed in function is called with the correct parameters.

```js
import { chowDown } from './file.ts';

interface Taco {
  filling: string;
  hasCheese: boolean;
  isCrispy: boolean;
}

describe('chowdown', () => {
  const eatTaco = (taco: Taco) => {};
  const expectedTaco = {filling: 'ground beef', hasCheese: false, isCrispy: true};

  it('eats the taco', () => {
    chowdown(eatTaco);
    expect(eatTaco).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedTaco);
  });
});
```

What I would like to do is something like

```js
spyOn(eatTaco);
//or
spyOn(window, 'eatTaco');
```

None of the proposed solutions that I have found online actually work for this infrequent spy event. Does anyone have any ideas as to how to actually spy on `eatTaco` properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `eatTaco` function with the following spy:

```
const eatTaco = jasmine.createSpy<(taco: Taco) => void>();
```

This TypeScript generics keeps you type safe.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the Type safety

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out.

The declaration of `eatTaco` had to change from this:

```js
  const eatTaco = (taco: Taco) => {};
```

to this:

```js
  const eatTaco = jasmine.createSpy();
```

This still works with TypeScript and Jasmine is smart enough to properly handle `toHaveBeenCalledWith(...)` without the typings. You do lose a bit of type safety here, but as long as you have the type declared in the actual code - your test doesn't technically need it.